# Exporting layers from MXD to geodatabase maintaining same TOC structure?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, file-geodatabase, layer-file

I have imported several shapefiles from different sources and have set up an MXD project with groups and subgroups of layer. I want to export the layers to a geodatabase while maintaining the same structure as the TOC, sending each group of layers to a different dataset.

How could I?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  To do this you will need to use ArcPy.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: File geodatabase doesn't support the concept of a folder, and the closest thing it does support, the feature dataset is *not intended for that purpose* (and could cause performance issues is misused). I recommend you reconsider your intention.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to export the lyrs to a gdb while maintaining the same
>   structure as the TOC, sending each group of layers to a different
>   dataset.

I think you probably misunderstood the relationship between a `.mxd` map file (or layer file) and datafiles such as .shp and geodatabases. A map/layer file does not store the actual GIS data, and it only stores other things like references and styles of GIS data. Vice versa, in ArcGIS, the GIS data formats like geodatabase cannot store the map/layer file either. There are stored separately.

By analogy, the .mxd/.lyr file is like your HTML file containing *links* to data such as images on your webpage. You can't store the HTML in an image file or an image file in your HTML file.